# How to write a new key in a .json object from within JS?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a hi.json with an object. In my JS, I do this:

```
var obj = require("hi.json");
```

But how can I write in that JSON file, using JS? Like this:

```
obj["key"] = "value";
// I want this to be saved in hi.json too
```

Comment: you have to write it to file. something like `writeToFile(JSON.stringify(obj))`. Where writeToFile is the logic of writing to file

Comment: @Mritunjay and then make sure no-one else is using it at the same time...

Comment: Are you talking about in the browser or server - If you are taking about browser JS, then you cannot write to a file for security reasons...

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I write in that JSON file, using JS? Like this:

Try using `a` element , `download` attribute , `data URI`

```
var obj = require("hi.json");

obj["key"] = "value";
// I want this to be save

var a = document.createElement("a");
a.download = "hi.json";
a.href = "data:application/json;charset=utf-8," + JSON.stringify(obj);
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

```js
    var obj = {
      "key": "undefined"
    };

    obj["key"] = "value";
     // I want this to be save

    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = "hi.json";
    a.href = "data:application/json;charset=utf-8," + JSON.stringify(obj);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
```